# Dart HttpRequest return future

Tags: dart, dart-html

I discovered Dart and developed a Rest Server with it. My understanding of the `future` is a cool async callback function but I didn't understand how it works to write in the data from a response.

I'm not talking about the client-side, my code look like this:

```dart
  getData(HttpRequest request) {
    dao.findAll().then((value) {
      print(value);
    });
  }
```

The value is printed correctly, now how can I return it in `request.response.write`?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `request.response.write` inside the value handler :

```dart
getData(HttpRequest request) {
  dao.findAll().then((value) {
    request.response
      ..statusCode = HttpStatus.OK
      ..write(value)
      ..close()
      ;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, but i already try and this doesn't display on browser for me. Maybe I miss something?

Comment: "Merci" my mistake was here, I closed the response after this call function. When the callback was call, the response was already closed!