# Dart HttpServer Cache

Tags: json, dart

I have Http server loading data from different server (through HttpClient). You can see the code here: [Dart HTTP server and Futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244612/dart-http-server-and-futures)

I am able to load response to JSON map and now I want to keep this map in memory until it's invalidated (I can get information on change way faster that whole set). What would be best way to save my JSON map to in memory object and retrieve it from memory until it needs to be refreshed?

Comment: You can write books about caching, so this question is very broad. What are your concrete requirements?

Comment: Hello again. Sure. If you take a look at working code from my last question, I need to persist values of JSOM Map parsedMap and serve further HTTP requests not from loadUrlBody(), but from this persisted object.

Comment: Should I use factory constructor for such simple case? https://www.dartlang.org/articles/idiomatic-dart/#factory-constructors

Comment: When you have JSON as Map you just put it in another map with the URL as the key. Vefore each request check if the URL is already in the map, if yes take the value, if no, send the request and store the result in the map. I don't see how this is related to factory constructor.

Comment: Okay, sounds easy. I thought it would be more complicated/was looking for best practice.

Comment: It can easily become way more complicated, but that depends on your requirements. When should cache entries became stale and be removed from the cache for example (after some delay, when some data changes that makes the cache entry invalid, ...). If you don't need such additional logic it's quite easy. Can the cache become to big. How do you recognize such a situation, what should be removed from the cache (the oldest, the biggest, ...)

Comment: Okay, it works fine in my case. Now it looks like I was overcomplicating things. I compare two time values on each request and if there is a difference bigger than ten minutes, I simply overwrite map with new values (like oldmap=newmap).

Comment: If this works for you. The simpler the better ;-)

Comment: Also you might want "bloom filter" if your map gets really big.  Make hash mechanism decoupled and easily replaceable so you will be able to modify it down the road or even replace it with some hardcore native cache with specialized hash functions and capable of moving old records to the memristor drive powered by the alien technologies

Answer (score 0):

Solved in comments above. Summary: if you need to keep value in very simple "cache" scenario, you can make a copy of the object and invalidate it by copying new values over.

```
main() {
  Map cachedMap = new Map();
  var lastCached = new DateTime.now();
  final Duration cacheDuration = new Duration(minutes: 10);
  HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 4040).then((HttpServer server) {
    print('listening on localhost, port ${server.port}');
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
      var now = new DateTime.now();
      if (lastCached.add(cacheDuration).isAfter(now) && cachedMap.isNotEmpty) {
        handleMap(request, cachedMap);
      } else {
//do something to fill map
      }
      ;

    });
  }).catchError((e) => print(e.toString()));
}
```